# Recursive prediction using vector autoregression

Tags: r

I use the Canada data in the vars package as an example. I want to use the first 48 observations to run the var, predict the next quarter, add the predicted data to the original 48 observations, use the 49 observations to run the var, predict the next quarter, add the new prediction to the 49 observations, re-run the var, reiterate the process until all observations are used. In the end, I hope to generate a dataframe that contain predicted values, which I can use to calculate RMSE. Below is my code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stats)
library(vars)
data(Canada)
Canada_df <- as.data.frame(Canada)
prefit2 <- Canada_df[1:48,]
locs <- data.frame()
while (i <= nrow(Canada_df) & i >=48){

  varfit <- VAR(y = prefit2, p = 6, type = 'const')
  pred <- predict(varfit, n.ahead =1)
  locs <- sapply(pred$fcst[1:3], function (k) k[ , 1]) %>% matrix(nrow = 1) %>% data.frame()
  colnames(locs) <- colnames(prefit)
  prefit2 <- bind_rows(prefit2, locs)
  i = i + 1
}
```

When I run the code, there is no error generated. However, there are still 48 observations in prefit2, meaning no prediction was appended during the while loop. Additionally, i turns out to be 5, so it looks like the loop stops when it becomes 5. Not sure where is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code and it actually ran as you expected. The only thing worth reminding is to declare i before the while loop. In this case, for example, you want to declare `i <- 48`.